# Using Console2 with the R terminal

Tags: r, console2

I am trying to configure Console2 to use the R terminal.

I created a new tab named "R" and under the shell directory I linked it to:
...\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe. Console 2 just hangs for a few seconds and then reappears in the corner of my desktop with the window completely resized as small as it will go. You cannot resize it in this state - it just jumps back. The only option is to quit.

If I instead link to ...\R\R-3.1.3\bin\R.exe it works fine except that if I alt-tab to another window and then return to the terminal I am unable to type anything in R tab for Console2 or delete previously typed characters. It's completely unusable and I have to restart.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've been experiencing myself and it seems to be a bug - it happens with most other shells I used under Console2. The only solution that worked for me was to use a modified version of Console2 called ConsoleZ, which is found under: https://github.com/cbucher/console - it has many other useful options and it's more actively developed. Hope it helps.